# Insert Data with Laravel/Lumen from server side

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a post request to add a product informations to database like id (UUID),image, name, price ,..etc .

currently i'm using :

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $uuid = Uuid::generate();

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $name = time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = storage_path('/app/images');
        $image->move($destinationPath, $name);


        $product = Product::create($request->all());

        return response()->json(['data'=>"product with id {$product->id} is created"]);
    }
```

Both fields uuid & Image URL are generated by the API and not from the information provided by the user so how can i save all the informations (server generated fields & fields provided by the post request) to the data base ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `array_merge()` function.

```
Product::create(array_merge($request->all(), [
    'uuid' => $uuid, 
    'image_url' => $imageUrl,
    'name' => $name,
    'price' => $price,
]));
```

Use `$request->except('_token', etc.)` instead of `$request->all()` when there is a csrf token or other fields you don't want to save. Make sure all fields are set as fillable on the model.